# Can different stainless steel grades corrode each other in contact

Tags: steel, corrosion

I am planning an application in which two stainless-steel grades can come into contact with each other. Can the differences in the grades cause corrosion in hot oily environment where water cannot be fully excluded? And how about in weak electrolytes such as in hot brackish water? For example, if the 1.4404 (316L) grade comes into contact with 1.4301 (304) grade. I am not talking about critical road infrastructure or similar, but it would still be nice to avoid the risk of corrosion already in the design phase.

Comment: determine if a voltage is generated between the two metals when dipped in electrolyte

Comment: @jsotola no external voltage applied. Just the possible difference caused by the varying nobilities of the metals.

Comment: I did not say anything about applying external voltage

Comment: Oh, sorry @jsotola. Now I got it. Thanks for the tip!